# Firebase database change not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code I'm trying to make a simple hit counter with. However, it doesn't work when I run it locally. When I start newHits as blank, it throws the error: Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'hits.number'.
When I start it at 1, it just doesn't change the value of the hits in the database. Any help is appreciated: I'm new to programming. Thanks so much!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var database = firebase.database();
  var hits;
  var newHits = 1;
  var hitsRef = firebase.database().ref('hits');
  hitsRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log("hitsRef.once called");
    hits = snapshot.val().number;
    console.log("hits: "+hits);
    newHits = hits+1;
    console.log(newHits);
  });
  hitsRef.set({
    number: newHits
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to do that by using transaction see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var database = firebase.database();
  var hitsRef = firebase.database().ref('hits/number');
  hitsRef.transaction(function(hits){
    console.log("hitsRef.once called");
    hits++;
    return hits
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **async** nature of once(). According to your code, both once() and set() are called for the same value of **i** at once.

If you want to test it, place your set() within a setTimeout() like,

```
setTimeout(function(){
        hitsRef.set({
        number: newHits
       });
    }, 2000);
```

You will see that your problem is solved but this is not the correct way.Try this instead,

```
    var i = 1;
    hitsRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log("hitsRef.once called");
    hits = snapshot.val().number;
    console.log("hits: "+hits);
    newHits = hits+1;
    console.log(newHits);
    })
    .then( function() {      // change starts here
        hitsRef.set({
        number: newHits
           });
      });
```

Your set() method will only be called when once() is done retrieving *hits*. This works because once() returns a promise and it is thenable.

Read these [then() in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).